Using plot_layout(guides = "collect") still leaves two legends that look the same. Do I need to keep both?
I have created a figure from separate correlation tests using ggcorrplot and patchwork. Here is the code below used to patch those figures together in Rstudio.
etcvirusup <- VIRUSDELAY_u + VIRUSCAT_u + VIRUSTRAIL_u + plot_layout(guides = "collect")
etcvirusdown <- VIRUSDELAY_d + VIRUSCAT_d + VIRUSTRAIL_d + plot_layout(guides = "collect")
etcvirusup / etcvirusdown + plot_layout(guides = "collect", widths = unit(c(8,1), c('cm', 'null')))

I was hoping that the plot_layout(guides = "collect") would leave one legend for the whole figure, but two are made.

Even though scales look the same, I assume they cannot be cropped out to one. legend and both must be kept in the final figure?  Thanks!

try (VIRUSDELAY_u + VIRUSCAT_u + VIRUSTRAIL_u) / (VIRUSDELAY_d + VIRUSCAT_d + VIRUSTRAIL_d) + plot_layout(guides = "collect")
